Derivatives of Poisson kernel.
In Stein book Singular integrals and differentiability properties, page 86 the following  is written:
Let $f \in L^{p}$ and $ u(x,y) = P_{y} * f (x) $ Where $P_{y}$ is the Possion kernel. then it is written that $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{2k-1} | \partial^{k}_{y} u(x,y)|^{2} dy \leq A(k) \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{2k} | \partial^{k+1}_{y} u(x,y)|^{2} dy $$
The proof of the estimate goes as follows:
$$ \partial_{y}^{k} u(x,y) = - \int_{y}^{\infty} \partial_{s}^{k+1} u(x,s) s^{k}s^{-k} ds $$
Now Schwartz inequality gives
$$
|\partial_{y}^{k} u(x,y)|^{2} \leq \frac{1}{2k-1} y^{-2k+1} \int_{y}^{\infty}  |\partial_{s}^{k+1} u(x,s)|^{2} s^{2k}
$$
From here Stein conclude the result. I don't see why, if we integrate in $y$ we get $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{2k-1} | \partial^{k}_{y} u(x,y)|^{2} dy \leq A(k)  \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{\infty} s^{2k} | \partial^{k+1}_{s} u(x,s)|^{2} ds dy $$
What tried to do is the followig: the right hand side is equal to
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} |\partial_{s}^{k+1} u(x,s)|^{2} s^{2k} \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{[y,\infty)}(s) dy ds $$
Then the inner integral is equal to $s$. But then this does not prove the formula written.
It is probably obvious but I just cannot see it now. Any help is appreciated.
